# minTime must be >= maxTime ? Java SDK

Tags: java-sdk

I'm trying to add a simple time bounds with the Java SDK to settle a transaction happening at a certain time.

Code used :

```
Instant unlockDate = Instant.now().plusSeconds(60 * 2);
    TimeBounds timeBounds = new TimeBounds(unlockDate.getEpochSecond(), 0);
Transaction transaction = new Transaction.Builder(sourceAccount)
      .addOperation(new PaymentOperation.Builder(destination,
          new AssetTypeCreditAlphaNum12("xxx", issuer), amount).build())
      .addTimeBounds(timeBounds)
      .addMemo(Memo.text("Memo")).build();
  transaction.sign(distributor);
```

But I get this error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: minTime must be >= maxTime

It seems you can't set the maxTime to 0 anymore.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for catching this. It's a bug in Java SDK, please upgrade to [0.3.1](https://github.com/stellar/java-stellar-sdk/releases/tag/0.3.1) and it should be fixed.